Error when installing libvirt-python via pip on Windows 11
I'm attempting to install the libvirt-python package using pip within my virtual environment on Windows 11. However, I encounter an error during the installation process. Below is the command I executed and the corresponding error message:
(venv) PS D:\PythonProd\Prod> pip install libvirt-python
Collecting libvirt-python
  Using cached libvirt-python-10.2.0.tar.gz (246 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


It appears that the pkg-config binary is necessary for compiling libvirt-python on Windows. How can I resolve this issue and successfully install the package on my Windows 11 system?
UDP: Now I am faced with the following error
py -m pip install libvirt-python                                     
Collecting libvirt-python
  Using cached libvirt-python-10.2.0.tar.gz (246 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: libvirt-python
  Building wheel for libvirt-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for libvirt-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      copying build\libvirt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      copying build\libvirt_qemu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      copying build\libvirt_lxc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      copying build\libvirtaio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      running build_ext
      Generated 285 wrapper functions
      Generated 1 wrapper functions
      Generated 1 wrapper functions
      building 'libvirtmod' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\build
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I
. -ID:\PythonProd\VBoxIntegration\venv\include -IC:\Users\Nikolay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\Nikolay\AppData\Local\Programs\Py
thon\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Window
s Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\inclu
de\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild/libvirt.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\build/libvirt.obj -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include -Wp,-DPy_LIMITED_API=0x03060000
      cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  error D8021: ­Ґ¤®ЇгбвЁ¬л© зЁб«®ў®©  аЈг¬Ґ­в "/Wp,-DPy_LIMITED_API=0x03060000"
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libvirt-python
Failed to build libvirt-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for libvirt-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects



Do it in msys2. Install gcc or llvm toolchains, make, pkg-config and other build tools and then python and libvirt developement packages.

Try python -m pip install libvirt-python  https://pypi.org/project/libvirt-python/#description

https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt-python/-/issues/7#note_623686805 , https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt-python/-/issues/6#note_513071066
